# C# file read lines find end of item

Tags: c#, file, readfile

I have a file like this...

```
2000,0, <-----ID
0,180000.100,190000.200
1,200000.100,210000.200
2,300000.100,210000.200
3,400000.100,400000.200
2001,0,
0,199999.001,100000.100
1,200000.000,200000.100
...
```

I can read the lines one by one using streamreader but i need to figure out how to get the first and last lines only for each ID group.  So for the example above i need...

```
0,180000.100,190000.200
3,400000.100,400000.200
```

Comment: Is zero after `2001,0` intentional? Should there also be a zero after `2000`?

Comment: Your question missing sample code - please make sure sample shows how you figuring out group boundaries.

Comment: So how do you define the lines that denote group boundaries?  Lines with less than 2 commas?  Lines without any commas?

Comment: Sorry, edited the sample doc they all have two commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try examining your inputs line by line and putting them inside a `List<string>`

Such as:

```
string str = ReadNextLine();
if(IsANewIDGroupHeader(str)){
  CreateNewIDGroup();
  NewIDGroup.Add(str);
}else{
  OldIDGroup.Add(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the overall length of the line, or the # of commas.

You'll have to save the lines in memory, as it's forward-reading.

That is, read line 1. <=1 comma? New Item, clear saves.
Next line, save to "firstItem" variable.
Each subsequent line, save to "lastItem" variable, overwriting existing value.

Once you hit another line with <=1 comma, take the two variables saved and write them out to your permanent save location or object.